# Makefile : file exists check not consistent

Tags: make

```Makefile
check: gen
#       ls -ltr file_name*
ifeq ($(shell test -s file_name && echo -n yes),yes)
        Do something with file_name and file_name1
else
       Do something else with file_name1
endif

# Will generate file_name and file_name1. Depending on the implementation , file_name can be empty sometimes.
gen: 
        <some command to generate file_name and file_name1>

clean:
        -rm -rf file_name*
```

When I do a `make check` without `make clean`, the `make check` always returns "Hello exists".

Doing a `make clean` and then a `make check`, it does not return the "Hello exists".

Note: in both cases, the `ls -ltr` in `gen` returns a non-empty file print.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ifeq ($(shell test -e file_name && echo -n yes),yes)
```

is evaluated as Make reads the Makefile, not as the commands are run. Thus if `file_name` exists when the Makefile is read, the `check` target will run `echo "Hello exists"`, otherwise it won’t.

Makefiles should really be described in terms of files as much as possible; in your case, `check` needs `file_name` and `file_name1`, so that’s what should be specified:

```make
check: file_name file_name1
        <run your checks>

file_name file_name1:
        <some command to generate file_name and file_name1>

clean:
        rm -f file_name file_name1
```

The checks themselves can involve any command you could run in your shell, including tests on the files, but you can’t make portions of the Makefile conditional on criteria that change during the Makefile’s processing (at least, not easily). In your case, you could do something like

```make
check: file_name file_name1
        test -s file_name && <do something with both files>
        ! test -s file_name && <do something with only file_name1>
```

or more explicitly, with escapes because this needs to run in a single shell invocation:

```make
check: file_name file_name1
        if [ -s file_name ]; then \
            <do something with both files> \
        else \
            <do something with file_name1> \
        fi
```